# Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally

Tags: git, github, git-bash

После команды `commit-m`  когда пишу   `git push` выводит ошибку

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/DuudeXX8/TripBaku-.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Помогите в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В самом вопросе уже есть ответ:

```
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Вы пытаетесь вылить на удаленный git репозиторий, но в текущей ветке уже есть изменения которых нет у вас, для этого сначала нужно забрать с удаленного репозитория все изменения чтобы можно было туда внести свои, просто выполните команду:

```
git pull
```

И после этого уже выливайте ваши изменения.

Comment: Лучше `git pull --rebase`.