# Не могу запушить изменения в репозиторий

Tags: git, github, git-push

Раньше пушил изменения без проблем. Написал код, появилась ошибка.

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<логин автора>/<название репозитория>.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Может, кто-то знает, как решить проблему.

Comment: git pull origin название ветки, на сервере лежат изменения, которых у вас нет. Впрочем, именно это вам и предлагают сделать: `You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') `

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master` (подставить соответствующие названия удалённого репозитория и ветки в нём)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758354/updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have-loca)