# Ошибка при попытке переноса файлов в гит репозиторий

Tags: git, git-push

При попытке сделать git push выходит ошибка. Посмотрите, в чём проблема?

```
Admin@DESKTOP-VJ0TN1P MINGW64 ~/dev/how-to-learn (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Admin@DESKTOP-VJ0TN1P MINGW64 ~/dev/how-to-learn (master)
$ git push
To https://github.com/Olga-0312/how-to-learn.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Olga-0312/how-to-learn.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Что непонятно во фразе *"You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again."*?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758354/updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have-loca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть изменения, которые ты не забрал с репозитория. Воспользуйся git pull origin master (или git pull), чтобы получить изменения, после чего уже сможешь сделать git push.

Также подмечу, что делать какие-либо изменения в мастере, даже будучи единственным разработчик, - это плохой тон. Старайся создавать отдельную ветку develop. Таким образом, в случаи аффекта, будет проще откатить изменения и master будет всегда актуальной веткой с рабочим функционалом, которую ты сможешь из любой точки мира получить и без проблем запустить.